# Mocking code run inside an rq SimpleWorker

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking, python-rq

I have code which uses [Python requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) to kick off a task which runs in a worker that is started with rq. (Actually, the GET request results in one task which itself starts a second task. But this complexity shouldn't affect things, so I've left that out of the code below.) I already have a test which uses rq's [SimpleWorker](https://python-rq.org/docs/testing/) class to cause the code to run synchronously. This works fine. But now I'm adding [requests_ratelimiter](https://github.com/JWCook/requests-ratelimiter) to the second task, and I want to be sure it's behaving correctly. I think I need to somehow mock the `time.sleep()` function used by the rate limiter, and I can't figure out how to patch it.

*routes.py*

```
@app.route("/do_work/", methods=["POST"])
def do_work():
    rq_job = my_queue.enqueue(f"my_app.worker.do_work", job_timeout=3600, *args, **kwargs)
```

*worker.py*

```python
from requests_ratelimiter import LimiterSession

@job('my_queue', connection=redis_conn, timeout=3600, result_ttl=24 * 60 * 60)
def do_work():
    session = LimiterSession(per_second=1)
    r = session.get(WORK_URL)
```

*test.py*

```python
import requests_mock

def test_get(client):
    # call the Flask function to kick off the task
    client.get("/do_work/")

    with requests_mock.Mocker() as m:
        # mock the return value of the requests.get() call in the worker
        response_success = {"result": "All good"}
        m.get(WORK_URL, json=response_success)
        
        worker = SimpleWorker([my_queue], connection=redis_conn)
        worker.work(burst=True)  # Work until the queue is empty
```

A [test in `requests_ratelimiter`](https://github.com/JWCook/requests-ratelimiter/blob/24e6303de3b39b393ecbd8b78ec17f39b2669e92/test/test_requests_ratelimiter.py#L21) patches the sleep function using a target path of `'pyrate_limiter.limit_context_decorator.sleep'`, but that doesn't work for me because I'm not declaring `pyrate_limiter` at all. I've tried mocking the `time` function and then passing that into the LimiterSession, and that sort of works:

*worker.py*

```python
from requests_ratelimiter import LimiterSession
from time import time

@job('my_queue', connection=redis_conn, timeout=3600, result_ttl=24 * 60 * 60)
def do_work():
    session = LimiterSession(per_second=1, time_function=time)
    r = session.get(WORK_URL)
```

*test.py*

```python
import requests_mock

def test_get(client):
    # call the Flask function to kick off the task
    client.get("/do_work/")

    with patch("my_app.worker.time", return_value=None) as mock_time:
        with requests_mock.Mocker() as m:
            response_success = {"result": "All good"}
            m.get(URL, json=response_success)
        
            worker = SimpleWorker([my_queue], connection=redis_conn)
            worker.work(burst=True)  # Work until the queue is empty
        
        assert mock_time.call_count == 1
```

However, then I see `time` called many more times than `sleep` would be, so I don't get the info I need from it. And patching `my_app.worker.time.sleep` results in the error:

> AttributeError:  does not have the attribute 'sleep'

I have also tried patching the `pyrate_limiter` as the `requests_ratelimiter` testing code does:

```
    with patch(
        "my_app.worker.requests_ratelimiter.pyrate_limiter.limit_context_decorator.sleep", return_value=None
    ) as mock_sleep:
```

But this fails with:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app.worker.requests_ratelimiter'; 'my_app.worker' is not a package

How can I test and make sure the rate limiter is engaging properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was indeed to use `'pyrate_limiter.limit_context_decorator.sleep'`, despite the fact that I wasn't importing it.

When I did that and made the mock return `None`, I discovered that `sleep()` was being called tens of thousands of times because [it's in a `while` loop](https://github.com/vutran1710/PyrateLimiter/blob/6ee9f52f298284e9afe605c92b3ebac18c7880a6/pyrate_limiter/limit_context_decorator.py#L85).

So in the end, I also needed to use [`freezegun`](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) and a [side effect on my `mock_sleep`](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/issues/47#issuecomment-324442679) to get the behavior I wanted. Now time is frozen, but `sleep()` jumps the test clock forward synchronously and instantly by the amount of seconds passed as an argument.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from unittest.mock import patch

import requests_mock
from freezegun import freeze_time
from rq import SimpleWorker


def test_get(client):
    with patch("pyrate_limiter.limit_context_decorator.sleep") as mock_sleep:
        with freeze_time() as frozen_time:
            # Make sleep operate on the frozen time
            # See: https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/issues/47#issuecomment-324442679
            mock_sleep.side_effect = lambda seconds: frozen_time.tick(timedelta(seconds=seconds))

            with requests_mock.Mocker() as m:
                m.get(URL, json=response_success)
                worker = SimpleWorker([my_queue], connection=redis_conn)
                worker.work(burst=True)  # Work until the queue is empty

            # The worker will do enough to get rate limited once
            assert mock_sleep.call_count == 1
```